# Best Approach for single/multiple time common Observable subscribe between components based on different data stream in Angular component

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

what is the best way to use different different data response subscribing using single observable inside Angular component.And Same observable using for multiple purpose in other component as well.

I am using the following ways:

**myservice:**

```
CommonFormObservable=new Subject();
```

**myComponent1:**

```
// first way
this.myService.CommonFormObservable.pipe(filter((data: any) =>
        (data.Type == "DayData" && data.DataType == "entry" && data.MessageKind =="READ"))).
        pipe(this.compUntilDestroyed()).subscribe((message: MessageModel)=>{
        //to do with message
        });
        
this.myService.CommonFormObservable.pipe(filter((data: any) =>
        (data.Type == "DayData2" && data.DataType == "out" && data.MessageKind =="READ"))).
        pipe(this.compUntilDestroyed()).subscribe((message: MessageModel)=>{
        //to do with message
        });
```

//second way

```
this.myService.CommonFormObservable.pipe(this.compUntilDestroyed()).subscribe((message: MessageModel)=>{
        if(data.Type == "DayData2" && data.DataType == "out" && data.MessageKind =="READ"){
        //to do with message
        }
        else if(data.Type == "DayData" && data.DataType == "entry" && data.MessageKind =="READ"){
        //to do with message
        }   
        
        });
```

**myComponent2:**

```
this.myService.CommonFormObservable.pipe(filter((data: any) =>
        (data.Type == "DataSet" && data.MessageKind =="CREATE"))).
        pipe(this.compUntilDestroyed()).subscribe((message: any)=>{
        //to do with message
        });
```

so which one from the above is the best way as per performance and memory perspective.And any other best way?

please give me suggestion.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The optimal way to work with observables in Angular is avoiding the .subscribe function in the components whenever it's possible.

To do so you, you should implement your //first way alongside an extra observable in the component and the async pipe, which will automatically handle the subscribe/unsubscribe from the observable when the component is created/destroyed.

In the component

```
commonFormData$ = this.myService.CommonFormObservable.pipe;
```

In the template

```
<div *ngIf="commonFormData$ | async as data">
  <div
    *ngIf="data.Type == 'DayData' && data.DataType == 'entry' && data.MessageKind =='READ'"
  ></div>
  <div
    *ngIf="data.Type == 'DayData2' && data.DataType == 'out' && data.MessageKind =='READ'"
  ></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

@bernatsampera is right, consider using the async pipe as much as possible and avoid manually subscribing in components.

What I would do would look like:

```js
const entryFormData$ = this.myService.CommonFormObservable
  .pipe(
    filter((data: any) =>(data.Type == "DayData" && data.DataType == "entry" &&data.MessageKind =="READ"))),
    this.compUntilDestroyed(),
    map((data: any) => /* do whatever you need to display the content (like formatting) */));

const outFormData$ = this.myService.CommonFormObservable
  .pipe(
    filter((data: any) =>(data.Type == "DayData" && data.DataType == "out" &&data.MessageKind =="READ"))),
    this.compUntilDestroyed(),
    map((data: any) => /* do whatever you need to display the content (like formatting) */));
```

And in the template:

```html
<div>{{ entryFormData$ | async }}</div>

<div>{{ outFormData$ | async }}</div>
```

The `async` pipe can be used everywhere, including`ngIf`, `ngFor`, etc.
If you need the value at several places you can consider do something like this to avoid using the pipe multiple times:

```
<ng-container *nIf="{{ entryFormData$ | async as entryFormData }}"
  <div>{{ entryFormData.foo }}</div>
  <div>{{ entryFormData.bar }}</div>
</ng-container>
```